# por que session.setAttribute no me coge lo que hay después de los espacios

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

llevo tiempo comiéndome el coco con esto.
Cojo unos apellidos de una base de datos mediante:

```
dbapellidos=(String)rs.getString("Apellidos");
```

Compruebo que obtiene los dos apellidos, separados por un espacio, todo esto en una clase. El problema es que cuando voy a mostrarlos en una página Jsp:

```
sesion.setAttribute("Apellidos", dbapellidos); //Esto está en la clase
<%=session.getAttribute("Apellidos")%> //Esto en la Jsp
```

Solo me coge el primer apellido. ¿Por qué?
Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda

Comment: No tiene nada que ver pero estas casteando un String a String en tu primera línea

Comment: al principio probé sin String, esto es una de las pruebas que hice para ver si así cogía el espacio, pero no está ahí el problema

Comment: Hace una semana me paso lo mismo, y termine haciendo un split(" ") por espacios, y agregar mas de un atributo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba en la clase

```
dbapellidos=(String)rs.getString("Apellidos");
sesion.setAttribute("Apellidos", dbapellidos); 
System.out.println(dbapellidos);
```

Luego prueba en el JSP

```
<%
String ape= (String) session.getAttribute("Apellidos");
System.out.println(ape);
%>
```

Por ultimo

```
<%=ape%>
```

Si estas en un INPUT o Elemento HTML no olvides envolverlo con comillas

```
<input type="text" name="apellidos" 
     value="<%=(String) session.getAttribute("Apellidos")%>">
```

Y si de esta manera te sigue dando error, verifica los output, y el HTML generado con Inspeccionar Elementos del Browser, quizás si lo este imprimiendo pero el navegador esta actuando sobre el resultado.

Comment: Al añadir String ape= (String) session.getAttribute(System.out.println(ape));
Me sale el siguiente error: The method getAttribute(String) in the type HttpSesion is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Comment: Se borro un pedazo del codigo, ya lo corregi. Fijate que el System.out.println() es un procedimiento sin retorno. No hubiera tenido sentido pasarlo por parametro.

Comment: System.out.println(ape); me imprime los dos apellidos, pero <%=ape%> solo uno

Comment: Si cambio la caja de texto (input) por un label, si me coge los dos apellidos

Comment: Lo estas haciendo asi?

<input type="text" name="appellidos" value="<%=(String) session.getAttribute("Apellidos")%>">

Notar que el valor esta envuelto en comillas, no habia entendido que era en un INPUT

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, por fin ha funcionado!!!